# an empty file after sending it to tcp server in python

Tags: python, tcp

I am new to python and i am trying to make a multithreded tcp server and client to be able to send files between them. I did write some simple codes for these two programs but every time I get empty file on server's site. The file does create in the folder but when I open it it is blank inside. I also tried to send .png files but windows photoviewer doesn't open them saying they are empty. I didn't find anyone encourting such problem so that's why i am asking

**Client.py**

```
import socket  # Import socket module

HOST = "localhost"  # Host address / name
PORT = 2137  # Reserves port for the service

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
client.connect((HOST, PORT))

fileToSend = open('test.txt', 'rb') 
print "File ready to be sent" 
l = fileToSend.read(1024)

while l:
    print "Sending the file"
    client.send(l)
    l = fileToSend.read(1024)

fileToSend.close() print "done" 
client.close()
```

**Server.py**

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

import sys

TCPHOST = "localhost"
TCPPORT = 2137
BUFFER_SIZE = 20


class ClientThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, HOST, PORT):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.HOST = HOST
        self.PORT = PORT
        print "New thread started for " + HOST + " on port " + str(PORT)

    def run(self):
        f = open('received.py', 'wb')
        while True:

                try:

                    data = conn.recv(1024)

                except socket.error, e:
                    print "Error receiving data: %s" % e
                    sys.exit(1)

                while data:
                    print "Receiving"
                    f.write(data)
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                f.close()


try:
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind((TCPHOST, TCPPORT))
    print "Socket created"
except socket.error, err:
    print "Failed to create socket" % err


threads = []

while True:
    server.listen(4)
    print "Waiting for connections"
    (conn, (HOST, PORT)) = server.accept()
    thread = ClientThread(HOST, PORT)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you actually want to do, because I see that you import SocketServer however you are not using it all.

If you are trying to run a simple socket server then the class ClientThread and all the other stuff about threads in that file are not necessary.

The following code in **server.py** will do the job

```
import socket

import sys

TCPHOST = "localhost"
TCPPORT = 2137
BUFFER_SIZE = 20

try:
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind((TCPHOST, TCPPORT))
    server.listen(4)
    print "Socket created"
except socket.error, err:
    print "Failed to create socket" % err

while True:
        print "Waiting for connections"
        (conn, (TCPHOST, TCPPORT)) = server.accept()
        try:

            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                f = open('received.py', 'wb')
                if data:
                   print "Receiving " + data
                   f.write(data)
                else:
                   f.close()
                   break;


        except socket.error, e:
            #pass
            print "Error receiving data: %s" % e
                #sys.exit(1)

        finally:
            conn.close()
```

However if you are trying to implement a threaded TCPServer using the ThreadingMixIn then you need to create a class that subclasses SocketServer and override its handle() function

Python documentation is quite helpful on this
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socketserver.html

(ThreadingMixin is at the bottom of the page)

Comment: I am trying to make a tcp server that allows multiple clients to connect to that server at the same time, so simple server is a bit usless for me, but i will try study with the link you have provided